# RasDial - Connecting to VPN server

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-7, delphi-xe, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to connect to VPN server, but with no success, I've created a connection with name "VPN".

```
var
 p : TRasDialParamsA;
 R : LongInt;
 hRAS : THRasConn;
begin
 FillChar(p, SizeOf(TRasDialParams), 0);
 p.dwSize := sizeof(TRasDialParams);
 p.szEntryName := 'VPN';
 R := RasDial(nil, 'VPN', p, 0, nil, hRas);
 MessageBoxA(0, pAnsichar(inttostr(r)), 'err!', $40);
end;
```

the error code comes up #6 (#606 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/163111 "The port is not connected.")

what can I do?

thnx.

Comment: Are you using any particular library for this? I mean, where are `TRasDialParamsA` and `THRasConn` defined?

Comment: Is it this? http://read.pudn.com/downloads67/sourcecode/comm/modem/241368/Dial-Delphi/RAS.PAS__.htm

Answer (score 1):

In Delphi 2009 and later, `RasDial()` maps to `RawDialW()`, which takes a `TRasDialParamsW` as input. But you are declaring `p` as `TRasDialParamsA` instead, so you are passing Ansi data to `RasDialW()` which expects Unicode data.

Drop the `A` and let `TRasDialParams` map to the correct type in all Delphi versions (you are already relying on that behavior when calling `SizeOf()`).

Likewise, you also need to fix your `MessageBox()` call as well. It is similarly broken in Delphi 2009+.

Try this:

```
var
  p : TRasDialParams;
  R : LongInt;
  hRAS : THRasConn;
begin
 ZeroMemory(@p, SizeOf(p));
 p.dwSize := SizeOf(p);
 p.szEntryName := 'VPN';
 R := RasDial(nil, 'VPN', p, 0, nil, hRas);
 MessageBox(0, PChar(IntToStr(r)), 'err!', MB_OK or MB_ICONINFORMATION);
end;
```

Comment: Hmm, I even searched for "Delphi RasDial" and only found third-party libraries and units. If this is a part of Delphi, what unit is it in?

Comment: @JerryDodge: [`RasDial()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377004.aspx) is a Win32 API function, but Delphi does not declare it in any of its Windows/RTL units, users have to declare it themselves, which is where third-party code comes into play, like the one you linked to. That does not change what I said in my answer, though.

Comment: @JerryDodge, you should ask a particular question regarding to that. There are number of translations of (R)RASAPI done before by enthusiasts while Borkadero never did that. Most notable is JEDI's one, as usual.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Yes, that's why I asked in the comments to the question. Seeing that it has both an `A` and `W` option, I know it has to be a third-party library.

Comment: @JerryDodge, it can be any of translations done. One you've linked appears to be very old and non-Unicode-aware.

Comment: @FreeConsulting I was asking which library because regardless, questions should always include that kind of information for debug purposes anyway.